# How to select and extract specific data in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame and I want to know how do i select data which contains a specific word for e.g. TissueA.

For one of my questions it says "How many of the samples are TissueA samples?"

To put it into context, i have a picture of the table in excel. The first column of each row is the gene identifier: (gene-symbol|entrez ID) e.g. "A2M|2" (A2M is the gene-symbol and 2 is the entrez database identifier for alpha 2 macroglobulin)

Each sample identifier is formatted as: TCGA-ID_Tissue# where the Tissue is either "TissueA" or "TissueB" e.g. "TCGA-AA-3548_TissueA"

I tried using
      `df[which(df$TissueA)]` which gives me an error.

I am basically trying to sort out all the patients who have Tissue A and also see how many.

[image: Screenshot of Table]

Comment: Homework or job application questions shld rly be marked as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df[grep("TissueA", names(df)]    # Extract

sum(grepl("TissueA", names(df))  # Count
```